# How agents will wait in the queue for there turn to go to the Delay section?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I used seize-move-release in order to move the agent with the resource. shown in the figure below.
[image]

**Problem**
Now the only problem is, how agents will wait in the queue (capacity 2) for there turn to go to the Delay section using resource. Explanation is in the image below.
[image]

**What i am trying to achieve:**
I mean agents wait in the queue (capacity 2). Once the delay(machine) gets empty, only then  resource transfer the agent from the queue to the delay.

**Note:**
I try to use service because Service block have queue too but I need the queue before the resource pool.
I hope I explain my problem well let me know if I miss some thing.

I used Wait Block for the agents to Wait but when wait capacity equals to 2 . Agents stop moving forward.
[image]

Comment: sorry, what queue are you talking about? Why not just use a queue with capacity 2 before `moveTo`?

Comment: I add a queue(capacity of 2) before `moveTo` but the `delay` capacity is only one so it is throwing an error because the `resource` brings the agent to the `Delay` which already has an agent in it.

Comment: exactly I think the `queue` will come before the `moveto` but we have to implement some sort of condition. So `resource` don't bring the agent from the queue to the `delay` when the `delay` already has an agent in it. but how?

Answer (score 0):

Use a "Wait" object ahead of `moveTo`.

Whenever the `delay` capacity decreases to zero ("on exit" code box of `delay` you can check it using `delay.size()==0?`), you can tell an agent in the "Wait" object to advance now, using `wait.free(agentToFree)`.

If you want to free the oldest agent, use `wait.free(wait.get(wait.size()-1))`

Comment: As for as I understand I have to add `if(delay.size()==0)
wait.free(wait.get(wait.size()-1));` in the "on enter" code box of the Wait block.
I tried and it did work, but once the agent number in the Wait block becomes 2, agent completely stops going forward. I also explain it above in an image kindly take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: no, think about it: it needs to be at the "on at exit" block of your `delay`, see my answer

Comment: I did use the condition in "on at exit" of the "delay" Block but agents are not leaving the "Wait" Block when the capacity is full. The same problem which I mentioned before in the comment.

Comment: try playing with it manually, it is the correct approach but you probably miss some logic. Add some buttons to manually trigger things, see how the model reacts. Zoom into the core issue and then report back in a new issue (or fix it directly).

Comment: It needs to be at the "on exit" block of the delay. Otherwise, the condition `delay.size() == 0` will never be true (on at exit = agent still occupies the delay block, while on exit = agent already left the delay block)